# При попытке GET запрос ошибка Undefined index: action

Tags: php

При попытке GET запроса в php выпадает ошибка Undefined index: action.

PHP скрипт (не весь кусок, а только тот, что касается проблемы):

```
} elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'getRunners') {
   $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, gender, finish_time FROM runners ORDER BY finish_time ASC";

   $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $runners = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($runners, array('fname' => $row['first_name'], 'lname' => $row['last_name'], 'gender' => $row['gender'], 'time' => $row['finish_time']));
}

    echo json_encode(array("runners" => $runners));
    exit;

}
```

Сам запрос GET вызывает javascript:

```
function getDBRacers() {
        $.getJSON("service.php?action=getRunners", function(json) {

some code here

}
```

Подскажите, как решить?

Comment: Что выдаёт var_dump($_GET)? и что выдаёт var_dump(isset($_GET['action']))

Comment: var_dump($_GET) выдает array(0) { }

Comment: var_dump(isset($_GET['action'])) выдает bool(false)

Comment: Это же в самом начале скрипта нужно проверять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации по `$.getJSON` данные на отправку на сервер формируются в виде объекта указанным вторым параметрам! Вы же указываете их в ссылку! Поэтому при `var_dump` у Вас `$_GET` пустой, т.е. данные не приходят на сервер (`array(0) {}`) как Вы прислали.
Попробуйте отправить запрос так:

```
$.getJSON( "service.php", { action: "getRunners"} )
.done(function( json ) {...}
```

[Источник](https://ruseller.com/jquery?id=17)

Comment: А $action в php как-то определить не нужно?

Comment: @NikitaMigushev он у вас в $_GET приходит!

Comment: прописал $.getJSON как сказали теперь при проверке var_dump($_GET)  выдает array(1) {
  ["action"]=>
  string(10) "getRunners"

Comment: И массив значений из базы данных вижу. Правда, он на странице html перестал отображаться. Сейчас буду разбираться.

Comment: @NikitaMigushev главное данные приходят и проблема решена! остальное уже другая задача)

Comment: Да, все уже разобрался. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    'action':'getRunners'
  },
  method: 'get',
  success: callback
});
```